# How do I add custom property to Express.Request in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm sorry for my poor English skills.

I created a new project using [express-generator-typescript](https://github.com/seanpmaxwell/express-generator-typescript).

> $ npx express-generator-typescript --use-yarn

I want to add additional properties to `Express.Request` for my custom middleware.
So I created `types/myRequest.d.ts` in `./src` and put and save the code as below:

```
// myRequest.d.ts
declare namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    myProp?: boolean;
  }
}
```

And I uncommented "typeRoots" in `tsconfig.json` and added "./node_modules/@types", "./src/types", and I tried to use the added property by creating a some middleware in `./src/routes/api.ts`. Here's the full code:

```
// api.ts
import { NextFunction, Request, Response, Router } from "express";
import userRouter from "./user-router";

function myMiddleware(req: Request, _res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  req.myProp = true;
  next();
}

// Export the base-router
const baseRouter = Router();

// Setup routers
baseRouter.use("/users", myMiddleware, userRouter);

// Export default.
export default baseRouter;
```

This builds fine, also IntelliSense in VS Code works fine and doesn't show any issues. However, when I run `yarn start:dev` I get the following error:

```
/home/me/dev/express-gen-ts/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:828
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/routes/api.ts:5:7 - error TS2339: Property 'myProp' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.

5   req.myProp = true;
        ~~~~~~

    at createTSError (/home/me/dev/express-gen-ts/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:828:12)
    at reportTSError (/home/me/dev/express-gen-ts/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:832:19)
    at getOutput (/home/me/dev/express-gen-ts/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1022:36)
    at Object.compile (/home/me/dev/express-gen-ts/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1326:43)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/me/dev/express-gen-ts/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1458:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/home/me/dev/express-gen-ts/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1462:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  diagnosticCodes: [ 2339 ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

So I can't do development in dev state. Of course if I don't use additional properties, the dev state is also available and works fine.

I think `express-generator-typescript` itself has some setting. Because changing "typeRoots" in `tsconfig.json` doesn't change the result. But I couldn't find it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whenever I run into this type of problem, I usually use "declare module" to add properties to Express's "Request" interface instead of declaring them in a namespace. This way I usually don't have to change anything in the tsconfig nor add any .d.ts files.

Add these lines to your api.ts code (note that in most cases you will need to reference the express-serve-static-core module as this is where the Request interface is declared):

```
declare module "express-serve-static-core" {
  interface Request {
    myProp?: boolean;
  }
}
```

Full file:

```
// api.ts
import { NextFunction, Request, Response, Router } from "express";
import userRouter from "./user-router";

declare module "express-serve-static-core" {
  interface Request {
    myProp?: boolean;
  }
}

function myMiddleware(req: Request, _res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  req.myProp = true;
  next();
}

// Export the base-router
const baseRouter = Router();

// Setup routers
baseRouter.use("/users", myMiddleware, userRouter);

// Export default.
export default baseRouter;
```

Normally this should make your newly added property available in other files as well, but you can of course export the manipulated Request interface just to be safe.

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem the way you pointed out.

Comment: what if I have tens of files where I use the request object? do I have to create a file this the extended Request object and import it all over the place?

Comment: @IonelLupu As I tried to clarify in the last sentence, this should normally make additional properties of the Request object available everywhere, since you are directly manipulating the Request interface, which is available by default in every file (at least in my projects with a default setup I can just use them in other files as well without importing/exporting them). Is that what you meant with your question? Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: I did so many changes to the config and declaration files that I don't know what made it work now. I ended up adding this to my tsconfig.json ` "files": ["./types/express/index.d.ts" ]`. The compiler doesn't complain anymore but the IDE still can't see the additional property. Using files and importing them returns " Cannot find module './types/express'" even if my IDE and the compiler can see the file. It's nuts

Comment: I extract these interface manipulations in separate `*.d.ts` files and place them in a directory called `types.`  If you add `export declare` they become available throughout the entire project.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you a way and hope it helps you.

in the file ./src/routes/api.ts you add this code (under import)

```
declare global {
     namespace Express {
         interface Request {
             myProp?: boolean;
         }
     }
}
```

then run again (doesn't seem to need `types/myRequest.d.ts` file)

Comment: Although I didn't choose your answer, thanks for the answer!